# Casting youtube from app to PC's browser

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I know it's possible to stream youtube from an app to a Smart TV. Since I have a laptop connected to my TV I'd like to do something similar. 
I like to cast from my Iphone's youtube app to my laptop (running WIN7 with youtube in the browser).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surf to youtube.com/tv#/ and the browser will "act" as a TV app. This way you can cast from apps to the browser.

Comment: Apparently YouTube has now an user agent filter that won't allow ordinary PC browsers to access youtube.com/tv. Theres a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-for-tv/gmmbpchnelmlmndfnckechknbohhjpge/) that re-enables that.

Comment: This has become adware unfortunately, I'd suggest to read the reviews before installing it... There are some alternative plugins available.